# QGIS 3 Grass 7.2 - Does not run

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-3

First: Grass did not run right out of the box when installed as instructed through the QGIS 3.0.x package. I had to install Grass separately and create a database path.

Now I am getting the following error: **tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified**

Thoughts?

See log message below:

> > Welcome to GRASS GIS 7.2.2
> >
> > GRASS GIS homepage: http://grass.osgeo.org
> >
> > This version running through: Bash Shell (/bin/bash)
> >
> > Help is available with the command: g.manual -i
> >
> > See the licence terms with: g.version -c
> >
> > See citation options with: g.version -x
> >
> > Start the GUI with: g.gui text
> >
> > When ready to quit enter: exit
> >
> > **tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified**
> >
> > Cleaning up temporary files...
> >
> > Done.
>
> Goodbye from GRASS GIS
>
> Default locale not found, using UTF-8
>
> Execution completed in 2.31 seconds Results: {'output':
>   }
>
> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
>   generated.
>   /var/folders/tm/6kzq8c3d28z9y85wf0bw579h0000gn/T/processing_7475f0c4cfc745e981e77acc2a1ae6fa/464bb56c81354bf89fefbf6531a83898/output.tif
>   You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find
>   more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: Hi, any chance that you switch to GRASS GIS 7.4? The 7.2 version is a bit dated...